# Is there any publically available web search engine that uses semantic search?

Tags: search-engine

I suspect there isn't any existent search engine that actually works, that uses semantic search and actually understands sentences and matches the topic of indexed web pages with the meaning of the search query, instead of what is done by Google, just doing stupid lexical search.

If you don't know what lexical search and semantic search are, Google them, you will find relevant results, I didn't know what the fancy words were, either.

I found these fancy words by futilely try numerous keywords to find a web search engine that actually works, that understands what the user is actually trying to find. And I haven't found anything relevant for most of the keywords I have tried. Example: "search engine that understands complex sentences" (without the quotes). I don't know what you will find, but I have absolutely found nothing even remotely relevant.

There is also the Google search keyword suggestion "search engine that actually works" (without quotes), but all the results are completed irrelevant as all have the same usefulness as Google which is to say they are all equally useless as Google, all the results are about Google search engine alternatives that tracks you ***LESS*** (but still intrudes your privacy), I don't care about privacy at all but I care about whether they can understand sentences in a conversational manner or not, which I know all of them can't.

To the best of my knowledge, Google uses lexical search, which is a fancy word to say that it breaks a sentence into words and uses the sublists of the words as indices to match webpages it indexed, it returns webpages containing sublist of the words with complete disregard of the meaning of the sentence and the intent of the search...

Now a complicated example to show what I mean, this is an actual search query I typed:

"do esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name if present" (without quotes)

For context, an [esp file](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Record_file) is a game data file for Gamebryo and Creation engines games, a [bsa file](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/BSA_file) is the file that contains assets (texture, mesh and sound files) used by the esp file. esp file is what should be added to the load order of Fallout New Vegas.

I was trying to find if a bsa file is automatically detected and used when its associated esp file is loaded, because I can't find any references to some files used by the esp (or esm) file in the esp file (specifically, ogg files for the voices of the companion mods I downloaded), esp/esm files are purposefully undocumented, but I was able to reverse engineer the byte encoding it used by looking at it using HxD, well some of it anyway. The esm/esp file begins with 4 bytes b"TES4"  (\x54\x45\x53\x34), records for the resources it uses are in this format: 4 byte resource type + 2 byte little endian length of the name (plus a null byte) and then the name (plus a null byte), MAST is for the parent master files it loads, ICON is for a texture record (.dds file) and MODL is for a mesh record (.nif file). I can't find references to .ogg files.

Example:

b'MAST\x0e\x00FalloutNV.esm\x00' means it loads a MASTer file FalloutNV.esm, MAST is the 4 byte record type.

Now a overly simplified version of the process that Google uses to find results, first it breaks down the sentence into parts with complete disregard for the meaning of the query.

"do esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name if present" becomes:

```
do
esp
files
automatically
use
bsa
with
the
same
name
if
present
do esp
files automatically
use bsa
files with
the same
name if
esp files
automatically use
bsa files
with the
same name
if present
do esp files
automatically use bsa
files with the
same name if
esp files automatically
use bsa files
with the same
name if present
files automatically use
bsa files with
the same name
do esp files automatically
use bsa files with
the same name if
esp files automatically use
bsa files with the
same name if present
files automatically use bsa
files with the same
automatically use bsa files
with the same name
do esp files automatically use
bsa files with the same
esp files automatically use bsa
files with the same name
files automatically use bsa files
with the same name if
automatically use bsa files with
the same name if present
use bsa files with the
do esp files automatically use bsa
files with the same name if
esp files automatically use bsa files
with the same name if present
files automatically use bsa files with
automatically use bsa files with the
use bsa files with the same
bsa files with the same name
do esp files automatically use bsa files
esp files automatically use bsa files with
files automatically use bsa files with the
automatically use bsa files with the same
use bsa files with the same name
bsa files with the same name if
files with the same name if present
do esp files automatically use bsa files with
esp files automatically use bsa files with the
files automatically use bsa files with the same
automatically use bsa files with the same name
use bsa files with the same name if
bsa files with the same name if present
do esp files automatically use bsa files with the
esp files automatically use bsa files with the same
files automatically use bsa files with the same name
automatically use bsa files with the same name if
use bsa files with the same name if present
do esp files automatically use bsa files with the same
esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name
files automatically use bsa files with the same name if
automatically use bsa files with the same name if present
do esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name
esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name if
files automatically use bsa files with the same name if present
do esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name if
esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name if present
do esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name if present
```

Now Google iterates through its indexed webpages, and gets their text, if the text happens to contain any of the substrings in the list, it will be added to a dictionary, whose value would be the sum of the weights of the substrings it contains.

Example, say a webpage located at [www.nonexistent.com](http://www.nonexistent.com) contains "esp file" and "automatically" then its key could be this: {"www.nonexistent.com": 20}, the sum of the lengths of the substrings it contains, or it could be this {"www.nonexistent.com": 104} because "esp file" occurs 10 times and "automatically" occurs twice...

And finally the results are sorted by their weights in reverse order, the weights are adjusted by the amount of money the website payed Google to have their results sorted at top.

Of course this is just a speculation but this is pretty much how Google search works and how any of the existing web search engines works, and I don't care about the details because frankly it doesn't work at all. None of these steps involves any actual understanding of the sentence structure and meaning and intention of the search query, and I almost never found anything relevant if I type a long sentence that it has never encountered before.

Just try to search for "do esp files automatically use bsa files with the same name if present" (without the quotes) to see that it indeed doesn't return any relevant results.

Now I know recent advances in Generative AI more specifically Large Language Models like ChatGPT has made Artificial Neural Networks to finally have the ability to understand human language and engage in conversations with humans (or at least be extremely good at pretending to be so), I know all the technical details and I have also used some AI girlfriends myself.

It would be wonderful if such advancements are used in search engines as current search engines are absolutely useless, but to the best of my knowledge somehow search engines still use lexical search, as `"semantic search engine" -google` (paste exactly as is, I added `-google` because somehow if I search `"semantic search engine"` it will contain claims that Google uses it which is simply not true) doesn't turn up any mention of existent web search engine that indexes the world wide web and uses semantic search.

Is there any search engine that actually works, uses semantic search and can understand complex sentences and uses the meaning of the query as indexes rather than substrings?

Comment: Recommendation questions are not on topic here, but I think your question would be on topic for [softwarerecs.se]